# How to change the header and footer style using the window.print method in java-script?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

When I use this window.print method
it showing the default header and footer
I want to add some styles and images in the header of the printed document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example For custom Print

```js
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
```

```css
.Print{
    display:none   !important;
 }
 .NoPrint{
    display:block  !important;
 }
 
nav {
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
 
 }
 
 footer{
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  margin-top:10px;
  }
 footer , nav > a{
 Font-size:30px; 
 width:100%;
    text-align: center;
 }
 
@media print {
 .Print{
    display: block !important;
 }
 .NoPrint{
    display: none !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav class="nav Print">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Print Logo</a>

</nav>

<nav class="nav NoPrint">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>

</nav>

<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
<footer class="Print">
Print copy rghit 
</footer>
<footer class="NoPrint">
 copy rghit 
</footer>
```

Comment: if we dynamically made one set of code it takes 20 pages then how to put header and footer for all pages

Comment: I can't make for all screen like static. Because that content is made dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print media query in your css like that:

```
@media print {
 /* styles go here */
}
```

It is also applied if the user decides to print the page without `window.print`

For further methods of styling for print take a look at the [`@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) rule. But keep in mind that [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-paged-media) isn't great yet

Comment: this is not for one page. I want to make it for more than 20 page

Comment: Oh, ok I've edited my answer. The @print rule is probably what you are looking for